# 100% fixed position overlaying screen

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website that has an autoplaying video as the hero element, and I currently have the video set to the following css:

```
#video-background {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

The purpose of which is to allow it to be full width. The fixed position is needed because the content below the video needs to be able to scroll over the video.

Unfortunately, even with the negative z-index, the video prevents you from clicking on content further down the page. It's still overlaying everything. When I right click anywhere the play, pause, unmute, etc. controls come up.

Not really sure how to keep this from happening. I've tried to play around with some of the settings, but anything (that I've tried, at least) that makes it full width ends up causing it to overlay everything.

Here's the html:

```
<video autoplay="" loop="" id="video-background" muted="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <source src="http://beta.mattgrossdesign.com/sites/default/files/wood%20autumn-HD.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**EDIT:** Solved it with a little help from a coworker. Here's the CSS:

```
div#layer_slider_1 {
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

div#after_layer_slider_1 {
  margin-top: 800px;
}
```

div#layer_slider_1 is the parent div. The div#after_layer_slider_1 is obviously the div right after it.

Thanks for the input.

Comment: Use this CSS: 'html, body{width:100%; height:100%;}'

Comment: Note that if you decide to use autoplay you better mute it by default, and disable the video initially on mobile devices. The former because no one likes audio popping up if you haven't asked for it. The latter because those users would want to save bandwidth. Also, you're making some strange decisions here. Set w and h to 100% inline, then overriding those in CSS with auto, and then setting min-values to 100%?! Finally, we'd need to see other code. because even though the previous notes hold, it should work nonetheless. If, and only if, the other elements are also positioned relatively.

Comment: Developing in Wordpress so that's why there's inline styles. Can't be helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with a little help from a coworker. Here's the CSS:

```
div#layer_slider_1 {
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

div#after_layer_slider_1 {
  margin-top: 800px;
}
```

div#layer_slider_1 is the parent div. The div#after_layer_slider_1 is obviously the div right after it. Needed to make the div below it overlay the video in order to avoid it from covering the whole page, even with the z-index.

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS property

```
html, body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%; 
}
```